# Formatting edits in Xcode

Tags: xcode, formatting

My friend and I are making an iOS app.  He has sent me code and I want to edit it, but I want my changes to be in a different color than the rest of the code so he knows where things changed.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt any editor supports this, it might be doable with some kind of plugin, but I doubt that exists either.

Simplest way to do is make a comment on the part you've changed and state your name, but that's a lot of work to use and later to keep track of.

I recommend you to use source control, such as [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/). You and your friend create commits and you can track back each commit, view what changed with that commit and even revert the code.

If you wish to share code with your friend, you'll need to have some kind of remote repository server or service, two most popular that I know of are [GitHub](https://github.com/) and [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/). I have used GitHub a lot and it offers great code diff view (difference in code before and after commit).

This service, grouped with a GUI client, which GitHub is offering for free (on [OS X](https://mac.github.com/) and [Windows](https://windows.github.com/)), works really good for team programming projects. If you choose BitBucket, they're offering their own tool, called [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), but it might be a bit intimidating. Good thing about GitHub client is that it works with every service, you just have to manually set up remote for non-GitHub projects.

---

I know this is not the answer you were looking for, but it is the one you need. Source control is (or should be) used by every professional programming team and knowing how to use it will help you if you ever choose to start a carrer as a programmer. And even as solo programmer, it's a great tool to have, especially when you start making a lot of changes and decide to undo them later on.